# Mongo Aggregation Returns [{}] for one of it's key:value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am use NodeJS, ExpressJS with Mongoose Mongo ORM.

My Schema is as follows.

```
const chatMessageSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { 
   type: String,
   default: () => (uuidV1().replace(/-/g, ''))
  },
  roomid: String,
  message: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  type: String, // text, card, qrt, attachment
  notes: [notesSchema],
  posted_by_user: String,
}, { 
  timestamps: { 
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at' 
}, 
  collection: 'ChatMessages'
});
```

The nested sub schema for notes is as follows;

```
const notesSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { 
      type: String,
      default: () => (uuidV1().replace(/-/g, ''))
    },
    roomid: String,
    messageid: String,
    message: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    type: String, // text, attachment
    posted_by_user: String,
}, { 
  timestamps: { 
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at' 
}});
```

Initially when a user creates a chatMessage the notes is default kept as an empty array initially [].

The user can explicitly create a note message after the message has been created, the notes is an array sub documents.

Now what happens is when I get a list of messages. I need to show posted_by_user which is an id of string. Against that id of string i perform a `$lookup` which gets the user profile. The aggregation is as follows.

```
return this.aggregate([
  { $match : {roomid: roomid} },
  { $sort: {created_at: -1} },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "RefUserProfiles",
      localField: "posted_by_user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "posted_by_user"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$posted_by_user" },
  { $skip: pageOptions.page * pageOptions.limit },
  { $limit: pageOptions.limit },
  { $sort: {created_at: 1} },

  { 
    $unwind: {  path: "$notes", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }  
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "RefUserProfiles",
      localField: "notes.posted_by_user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "notes.posted_by_user"
    }
  },
  { 
    $unwind: { path: "$notes.posted_by_user", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } 
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      created_at: { $last: "$created_at" },
      roomid: { $last: "$roomid" },
      message: { $last: "$message" },
      notes: { $addToSet: "$notes" },
      type: { $last: "$type" },
      posted_by_user: { $last: "$posted_by_user" },
      read_by_recipients: { $last: "$read_by_recipients" },
    }
  }
]);
```

Now since in some cases the notes for some messages is an empty array, so for that very particular case the object I get in responses is like `[{}]`. Is this how it is suppose to be. or is there a better use case involved.

For example the response I get based on this query is as follows.

```
"conversation": [  
    {
        "_id": "7cdbf630e6ec11e79166559abfb987ac",
        "created_at": "2017-12-22T07:48:23.956Z",
        "roomid": "aacc6b70e68211e79166559abfb987ac",
        "message": {
            "text": "message 1"
        },
        "notes": [{}],
        "type": "text",
        "posted_by_user": {
            "id": "4d6fd5a95d57436d944586a1d5b2b2ff",
            "name": "Adeel Imran",
            "profilePicture": "",
            "phone": "",
            "email": "",
            "designation": "",
            "type": "user"
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "80d91470e6ec11e79166559abfb987ac",
        "created_at": "2017-12-22T07:48:30.648Z",
        "roomid": "aacc6b70e68211e79166559abfb987ac",
        "message": {
            "text": "message 4"
        },
        "notes": [
           {
                "posted_by_user": {
                    "id": "86049b3d28f640a8a6722c57b73a292e",
                    "name": "Paul Johnson",
                    "profilePicture": "",
                    "phone": "",
                    "email": "",
                    "designation": "",
                    "type": "sp"
                },
                "type": "text",
                "message": {
                    "text": "yeah "
                },
                "messageid": "26401d30e5a511e7acc4c734d11adb25",
                "roomid": "27d3ed80e0cc11e78318b3cd036890f2",
                "updated_at": "2017-12-20T16:45:44.132Z",
                "created_at": "2017-12-20T16:45:44.132Z",
                "_id": "38ad3750e5a511e7acc4c734d11adb25"
            }
        ],
        "type": "text",
        "posted_by_user": {
            "id": "4d6fd5a95d57436d944586a1d5b2b2ff",
            "name": "Adeel Imran",
            "profilePicture":"",
            "phone": "",
            "email": "",
            "designation": "",
            "type": "user"
        },
    }
],
```

Any suggestions or directions for this will be highly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time out to review this question.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you perhaps post some sample data to reproduce this exact behaviour and also your desired result.

Comment: @dnickless sir I have added some sample data for you to check. The first index is the problem where it says ```[{}]``` i want to show ```[]``` the second index of ```conversation``` array is where I have a notes element.